# Join within an "exists" subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am wondering why when you join two tables on a key within an exists subquery the join has to happen within the WHERE clause instead of the FROM clause.

This is my example:

Join within FROM clause:

```
SELECT payer_id
  FROM Population1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (Select *
          From Population2 join Population1 
            On Population2.payer_id = Population1.payer_id)
```

Join within WHERE clause:

```
SELECT payer_id
  FROM Population1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (Select *
           From Population2
          WHERE Population2.payer_id = Population1.payer_id)
```

The first query gives me 0 results, which I know is incorrect, while the second query gives the the thousands of results I am expecting to see.

Could someone just explain to me why where the join happens in an EXISTS subquery matters? If you take the subqueries without the parent query and run them they  literally give you the same result.

It would help me a lot to remember to not continue to make this mistake when using exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the first query makes little to no sense at all. So, you are joining the tables `Population1` with `Population2`, and you are saying that if it exists any row at all as a result of that join, then don't return anything from `Population1`. That's why you get 0 rows

Comment: Show some sample data from the 2 tables, and the expected output.  Then we can help you.

Comment: And the second query is showing you all the rows in ```Population1``` where there is no corresponding record in ```Population2```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to understand the distinction between a regular subquery and a correlated subquery.

Using your examples, this should be easy.  The first `where` clause is:

```
where not exists (Select 1
                  from Population2 join
                       Population1
                       on Population2.payer_id = Population1.payer_id
                 )
```

This condition does *exactly* what it says it is doing.  The subquery has no connection to the outer query.  So, the `not exists` will either filter out all rows or keep all rows.

In this case, the engine runs the subquery and determines that at least one row is returned.  Hence, `not exists` returns false in all cases, and the nothing is returned.

In the second case, the subquery is a correlated subquery.  So, for each row in `population1` the subquery is run using the value of `Population1.payer_id`.  In some cases, matching rows exist in `Population2`; these are filtered out.  In other cases, matching rows do not exist; these are in the result set.

Comment: Thank you! I should have recognized this.

So, to validate my understanding, since I am including P1 within the FROM clause in the first query, I am not referencing the same instance of the table from the parent query and therefore not connecting to the parent query in any way.

Whereas, since I use P1 in the WHERE clause in the second query, this makes it a correlated subquery and it DOES reference the parent query's P1 table. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The first example is not actually reffering to the base table which creates a logic that is unpredictable.

Another way to do the same logic would be:

```
SELECT payer_id
FROM Population1 P1
LEFT JOIN Population2 P2 ON
    P2.Payer_Id = P1.Payer_Id
WHERE
    P2.Payer_Id IS NULL
```

Comment: The logic is predictable in the first query -- just not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You qry return `ROW EXISTS` always if exist even if there is one result row.

```
Select *
from Population2 
join Population1 on Population2.payer_id = Population1.payer_id
```

If exist at least one row from this join (and for sure there exists), you can imagine your subqry looks like:

```
select 'ROW EXISTS'
```

And result of:

```
select * 
from Population1
where not exists (select 'ROW EXISTS')
```

So your anti-semijoin return:

payer_id 1 --> some ROW EXISTS -> dont't return this row

payer_id 2 --> some ROW EXISTS -> dont't return this row